# Custom error placement not working in Jqueryvalidation plugin

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for validating my form data ,I have a fileupload element and then a button ,which opens browsing window to select file, as default error message is displayed between fileuplad element and button,I want to display this error message after button. I have tried many syntax as other similar question available on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

My jsp code is:

```
<tr>
     <td>Browse Query File:</td>                    
     <td>
          <span id="input_span" style="background-color: red">  
            <INPUT type="text" id="inputfilepath" name="inputfilepath" placeholder="Query File" autocomplete='off' class="text" readonly="true" onclick="hidehint();" style="margin-left: 10%">

            <input type="file" name="upFile" id="upFile"  class="file" onchange="return do_upload(this.value);"/>
            <input type="button" value="Browse" class="content_button2" onclick="do_click();"/> 
         </span>
         <span id="error_span">  </span>

       </td>
     </tr>
```

I want my error message to be displayed in span having id-"error_span" on after it.

I have tried suggested code as:

```
 errorPlacement: function(label, element)
              {

                  if(element.attr("name") === "inputfilepath") 
                  { 
                      alert("call");
                      error.appendTo($('#error_span'));
                  }

                  else
                  {       
                       error.insertAfter(element);
                  }
              },
```

I also tried:

```
                    error.appendTo(element.parent("span").next("span"));
```

But it did't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
rules: {
//rule stuff
}
groups: {
    fileUpload: "upFile upButton"
},
errorPlacement: {
    function(error, element) {
        if(element.attr("name") == "upFile") {
                error.insertAfter("#upButton");
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
}
```

Be sure and give your button the name "upButton" for this to work.

You are basically saying you want to group those elements, and the error placement says, in the event that there is a validation error on the upFile, you want that error message to display after the upButton element.